# Why won't these ul's float correctly in IE7?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I'm attempting to get this menu working in IE7. I've squashed every bug but this one. 
When you hover a list item, the UL's within the drawer that pops out won't float next to one another properly. If you look at the page in Chrome, that's how I was setting up the CSS before (display inline block, etc). That didn't work either so I tried floating them left.

Floating left fixed an issue I had with extra text-indent on the left of each li, but the ul's still will not float properly.

Does anyone have any ideas?

http://playground.willpracht.net/megaMenu.html

Answer (score 0):

Redo your code to remove as many of the > selectors as you can. They are making everything much harder to deal with. It's like giving everything an id, and makes overriding things longer and longer and longer.
Honestly I would have sub-divs instead of just menus, because you're making the first li's look like headers but semantically making them no different from all the other links. Actual headers with links inside make more semantic sense. For example there's a link called tools and then the rest of the sibling links are... tools.

Anyway, when floating things, look at your widths. I see a lot of elements with no widths declared at all. In IE, with floats, this is important. I would set widths (they can be in  em if you want) of the sub-divs, and then widths for the floating ul children inside. Their combined widths together should not equal 100%. For example, if a div is 140px wide, don't try two floated ul's inside each with widths of 70px, even though that should fit, and will in most browsers.

I have some example mega menus if you'd like to see, but there are many already out there and I don't believe I have one with floating ul's inside the submenu.